# Firebase Auth - Import Users as Disabled

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm importing users from my company's G Suite account to a Firebase application. The import follows the ['import users without passwords'](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users#import_users_without_passwords) process to import the users with Google as the OAuth Provider.

Some of our accounts in G Suite are suspended, and I'd like that to carry over when the user is imported to Firebase - so the Auth account is disabled. So far, the only method to disable a Firebase Auth account I've found is manually through the Firebase Console.

Is there a method for setting a user as disabled when importing using `admin.auth().importUsers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `disabled: true` into the imported users should work, but the documentation is quiet about it.

If that doesn't work, the closest is to [disable the users through the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) immediately after importing them:

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
  disabled: true
})
```

Comment: Interesting, wondering if the `disabled` prop works when importing the user.

Comment: I quickly checked and you should be able to pass `disabled: true` to the import too. Let me know whether that works. If it *doesn't* work, it sounds like a valid feature request. If it *does* work, we should document it (better).

Comment: I tried this today and can confirm the `disabled: true` property when importing a user sets the user as disabled.

Comment: Thanks for checking Brett. I'll add a note that the docs should contain an example of this.